# Looping through multiple arrays - Pushing into multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

Currently I have three arrays. `AppNames` which is an application Name. `Number of AddOns` which is the number of add ons each application is using. (Both of these arrays are used together. E.G *"cirr-contentful-demo" has 1 add on*).

Look Below:

```js
var prodArrayAppName = [],
  stgArrayAppName = [],
  devArrayAppName = [],
  prodNoAddOns = [],
  stgNoAddOns = [],
  devNoAddOns = [];

var appNames = ["cirr-contentful-demo", "cirr-contentful-handler-backup", "cirr-test-app"];

var numberAddOne = [1, 5, 7]

var production = [{
    "id": "16",
    "heroku_application": "cirr-contentful-demo",
    "stage": "Production"
},
{
    "id": "4",
    "heroku_application": "cirr-contentful-handler-backup",
    "stage": "Staging"
},
{
    "id": "9",
    "heroku_application": "test-backup",
    "stage": "Development"
}];
```

What I need is to loop through the `production` array of objects, match the `heroku_application` name to the *name in the `appNames`* array. Once found check the stage type *example: Production, Staging, Development*.

The push the application name to the correct array. E.G Production applications to `prodArrayAppName`. Then grab the number of addOns that application has and put it into the correct `NoOfAddons`. E.G prodArrayAppName.

Meaning the end game should look like:

```
prodArrayAppName = [cirr-contentful-demo]
prodNoAddOns = [1]

stgArrayAppName = [cirr-contentful-handler-backu]
stgNoAddOns = [5]

devArrayAppName = [test-backup]
devNoAddOns = [7]
```

This Is the code I have tried so far, but so far getting no luck:

```js
production.forEach(function(a) {
  appNames.forEach(function(b) {
    numberAddOne.forEach(function(c) {
      if (a === b.heroku_application) {
        if (b.stage === "Production") {
          prodArrayAppName.push(b.heroku_application);
          prodNoAddOns.push(c);
        } else if (b.stage === "Staging") {
          stgArrayAppName.push(b.heroku_application);
          stgNoAddOns.push(c);
        } else {
          devArrayAppName.push(b.heroku_application);
          devNoAddOns.push(c);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: I suppose my questions is "How to loop through multiple arrays and push into other arrays", Sorry for the poorly worded question. I tried to say what I was meaning by showing what the end goal should look like?

Comment: someone would say, SO is not a code market, please show what you tried.

Comment: I have tired nesting loops:

  `production.forEach(function(a) {
            appNames.forEach(function(b) {
              numberAddOne.forEach(function(c) {
                if (a === b.heroku_application){
                  
                }
            });
        });
      });`

I'm super stuck and some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us your trying code.Put it in the question.If there is a problem we will help

Comment: Okay I have updated the questions with my attempt so far.

Comment: Your production array is wrong.You have to put a comma after {
                    "id":"4",
                    "heroku_application":"cirr-contentful-handler-backup",
                    "stage" : "Staging"
                    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need explicit loops *at all* to acomplish this - make use of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var init = {
    DevelopmentAppName:[],
    DevelopmentNoAddOns:[],
    StagingAppName:[],
    StagingNoAddOns:[],
    ProductionAppName:[],
    ProductionNoAddOns:[],
};

var appNames = ["cirr-contentful-demo", "cirr-contentful-handler-backup", "cirr-test-app"];

var numberAddOne = [1,5,7]

var production = [
                    {
                    "id":"16",
                    "heroku_application":"cirr-contentful-demo",
                    "stage" : "Production"
                    },
                    {
                    "id":"4",
                    "heroku_application":"cirr-contentful-handler-backup",
                    "stage" : "Staging"
                    },
                    {
                    "id":"9",
                    "heroku_application":"test-backup",
                    "stage" : "Development"
                    }];
                    
var result = production.reduce(function(p,c){
     var idx = appNames.indexOf(c.heroku_application);
     p[c.stage + 'AppName'].push(c.heroku_application);
     p[c.stage + 'NoAddOns'].push(numberAddOne[idx] || 0);
     return p;
}, init);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is `Array.reduce` not a looping mechanism?

Comment: @Rajesh of course it is. (I said *explicit* loops!)

Comment: I'm getting an error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined on line : 
p[c.stage + 'AppName'].push(c.heroku_application); Whenever i take the p out of the line it runs but doesnt input anything

Comment: @user3180997 - so debug it! add `console.log(c.stage)` on the line above the one failing - what does it output?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need nested loops.

- For each project in `production`:

  - Find the index of the project's `heroku_application` in `appNames`. We'll use that to find the number.
  - Switching on the project's `stage`, add the project's name to (stage)ArrayAppName, and the project's cross-referenced number to (stage)NoAddOns.

---

```
production.forEach(function(project) {
  var index = appNames.indexOf(project.heroku_application);
  if (index === -1) { return; }

  switch (project.stage) {
    case "Production":
      prodArrayAppName.push(project.heroku_application);
      prodNoAddOns.push(numberAddOne[index]);
      break;
    case "Staging":
      stgArrayAppName.push(project.heroku_application);
      stgNoAddOns.push(numberAddOne[index]);
      break;
    case "Development":
      devArrayAppName.push(project.heroku_application);
      devNoAddOns.push(numberAddOne[index]);
      break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have tried has some problems.The condition check you used  if (a === b.heroku_application) itself is wrong.Try the code given below

```
var prodArrayAppName = [], stgArrayAppName = [], devArrayAppName = [], prodNoAddOns = [], 
stgNoAddOns = [], devNoAddOns = [];

var appNames = ["cirr-contentful-demo", "cirr-contentful-handler-backup", "cirr-test-app"];

var numberAddOne = [1,5,7];

var production = [
                {
                "id":"16",
                "heroku_application":"cirr-contentful-demo",
                "stage" : "Production"
                },
                {
                "id":"4",
                "heroku_application":"cirr-contentful-handler-backup",
                "stage" : "Staging"
                },
                {
                "id":"9",
                "heroku_application":"test-backup",
                "stage" : "Development"
                }];

                production.forEach(function(a) {                    
                         for(var i=0;i<appNames.length;i++)
                         {
                             if(a.heroku_application==appNames[i])
                             {
                                    if(a.stage==="Production")
                                    {
                                        prodArrayAppName.push(appNames[i]);
                                        prodNoAddOns.push(numberAddOne[i]);
                                    }
                                    else if(a.stage==="Staging")
                                    {
                                        stgArrayAppName.push(appNames[i]);
                                        stgNoAddOns.push(numberAddOne[i]);
                                    }
                                    else if(a.stage==="Development")
                                    { 
                                        devArrayAppName.push(appNames[i]);
                                        devNoAddOns.push(numberAddOne[i]);
                                    }

                             }
                         }                          


                });

            //checking code 
            prodArrayAppName.forEach(function(a) {
            alert(a);
            });
```

Comment: this returns an empty array unfortunately :(

Comment: No I have tried it .I will edit with the complete code

Comment: @user3180997 Answer has been updated with full code.Please try again